# A species of humanoids can see perfectly well under both sunlight and starlight. What's their eye morphology like?

Tags: science-based, humanoid, vision, senses

Assume a species of humanoids that can see under both starlight (no sun, no moon, clear skies) and sunlight as well as humans during the day. Let's assume the light levels are roughly the same as here on earth. Eyes aside, their physiology and overall build is the same as ours.

How should their eyes be shaped to allow them such acuity and broad range of illumination?

Answer (score 8):

The eyes of a feline or any nocturne predator come to mind:

- slit pupils, to allow for a wide opening with low light level and prevent saturation of the eye in high luminosity
- [tapetum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum) to reflect back the light not absorbed by the photo-receptors and increase therefore the light available for them

With those two adaptations nocturnal predators are able to hunt and survive relying on the naturally available light.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't hit the "_as well as humans during the day_" requirement, because those animals _also_ have a higher rods-to-cones ratio (giving substantially worse color vision) and the tapetum lucidum (and to a lesser extent) the slit pupil also increases blurring.

Answer (score 0):

Your humanoids can see under both starlight and sunlight.

To see in very **very low light**, their eyes have:

- Large cornea and pupil.
- Retinas with high rod density.
- Layer behind the retina called the tapetum lucidum, which reflects
  the light back to the retinas one more time

.

To see in **very bright light**, their eyes have:

- Pupils that could constrict to very small aperture.
- Additional eyelids which are transparent but absorb a large amount of
  light (like dark sunglasses).

Answer (score 0):

**Infrared vision**

Humans daytime vision is so good, there is no way to match this level. [Daytime illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight#Intensity_in_different_conditions) is about 100,000 lux, starlight illumination is 0.0002-0.002 lux. Even with perfect photon capture, this creature would need eyes hundreds of times bigger to capture that much light - and I dismiss it as an unfeasible option.

More realistic is the infrared vision. At night, landscape illumination in infrared spectrum is much brighter than in visible spectrum. A species can (potentially, this is biologically complicated problem) develop infrared vision to match their daytime vision.

Comment: Infrared sensing is dependent on the sensor (eyeball) temperature being well below the temperature of what you're looking for. Creatures with infrared sensing capability, such as pit vipers, are generally cold blooded and primarily hunt warm blooded creatures at night. Such a creature would be unlikely to be high metabolism, warm blooded, or highly active.
P.S. it is for the same reason that the James Webb telescope needs to be very cold to see infrared.

Comment: @Brianorca "Infrared sensing is dependent on the sensor (eyeball) temperature being well below the temperature of what you're looking for" - citation needed. All the uncooled IR cameras in the world are somehow working (though not as good as cooled IR cameras).

Comment: You can get about 10X improvement by having the enclosure cooled and limiting the background noise. That is with the detector still uncooled. Although you can also cool the detector. So being cooler can definitely help. The uncooled bolometer arrays that are available are much slower and much less sensitive than cooled semiconductor detectors.  Also there is less flexibility of wavelength range. For comparison, a pit viper neuron has a sensitivity of about .003 C according to the one abstract where commercialized microbolometers are probably 0.050 C.